# How to use golang to convert a multi-line json to one-line json?

Tags: json, go

How can I convert a multi-line json to a one-line json using Go?

From:

```
{
          "release_date": "2004-11-09",
          "status": "retired",
          "engine": "Gecko",
          "engine_version": "1.7"
        }
```

To:

`{"release_date":"2004-11-09","status":"retired","engine":"Gecko","engine_version":"1.7"}`

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Compact

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`json.Compact()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Compact) does exactly this:

> ```
> func Compact(dst *bytes.Buffer, src []byte) error
> ```
>
> Compact appends to dst the JSON-encoded src with insignificant space characters elided.

`json.Compact()` is superior to unmarshaling and marshaling again, as it works with any valid JSON, and is much-much faster (it doesn't create and throw away Go values). It's also superior to using any regexp, again, it's much-much faster and regexp does not understand JSON syntax fully, so it might result in data loss.

For example:

```
func main() {
    dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
    if err := json.Compact(dst, []byte(src)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dst.String())
}

const src = `{
          "release_date": "2004-11-09",
          "status": "retired",
          "engine": "Gecko",
          "engine_version": "1.7"
        }`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-a1Ouv4-D4j)):

```
{"release_date":"2004-11-09","status":"retired","engine":"Gecko","engine_version":"1.7"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unmarshal the multi-line JSON into a `struct` (or alternatively a `map[string]any{}`) and then marshal it to a string without any indent options. So, something like this:

```
    v := struct {
        ReleaseDate string `json:"release_date"`
        Status      string `json:"status"`
        Engine      string `json:"engine"`
        Version     string `json:"engine_version"`
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &v); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
    } else if bytes, err := json.Marshal(v); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", string(bytes))
    }
```

([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/YnmaC9ktoIS))

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know which kind of json you will get
just use like this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

const js = `
{
    "release_date": "2004-11-09",
    "status": "retired",
    "engine": "Gecko",
    "1": "1.7"
}
`

func main() {
    helper := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &helper)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &helper) failed. Error:  %v\n", err)
        return
    } 
    
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(helper)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("json.Marshal(helper) failed. Error:  %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
        
}
```

Try [here](https://play.golang.com/p/tNoraFQlXjW)

**And don't use replacing spaces because you can damage json values**